# Derivative of the integral of a complicated rational function

Tags: integration, derivatives, numerical-calculus

I would like to compute the derivative of the integral of a *complicated rational* function $W(x_0, \ldots, x_3 ,y_0, \ldots, y_3,\xi,\eta)$, with respect to any of the $x_0, \ldots, x_3 ,y_0, \ldots, y_3$. For example:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0} \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 W(x_0, \ldots, x_3 ,y_0, \ldots, y_3 \xi,\eta) \; d\eta \;d\xi
$$

I have considered moving the derivative inside the integrals like so

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\partial W(x_0, \ldots, x_3 ,y_0, \ldots, y_3,\xi,\eta)}{\partial x_0} \; d\eta \;d\xi
$$

But this would lead to [expression swell](http://kfe.fjfi.cvut.cz/%7Eliska/ca/node53.html) because of the complexity of $W(x_0, \ldots, x_3 ,y_0, \ldots, y_3,\xi,\eta)$. Furthermore, doing this precludes automatic differentiation. I am not quite sure how to proceed and wonder if there are techniques for solving such problems.

---

**Update**

$$
W = \mu \left[ 0.5 {{\left( \frac{{v_1} \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) }{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}+\frac{\left( 1-{v_0}\right)  {u_{10}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}\right) }^{2}}+0.25 {{\left( \frac{{{\left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) }^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}+\frac{{{{u_{10}}}^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}-1\right) }^{2}}+0.25 {{\left( \frac{{{{v_1}}^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}+\frac{{{\left( 1-{v_0}\right) }^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}-1\right) }^{2}}\right] +0.5 \lambda  {{\left[ 0.5 \left( \frac{{{\left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) }^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}+\frac{{{{u_{10}}}^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}-1\right) +0.5 \left( \frac{{{{v_1}}^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}+\frac{{{\left( 1-{v_0}\right) }^{2}}}{{{\left( \left( 1-{v_0}\right)  \left( 1-{u_{11}}\right) -{v_1} {u_{10}}\right) }^{2}}}-1\right) \right] }^{2}}
$$

where

$$
u_{00} = \frac{\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_3}\right)  {v_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_2}\right)  {v_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_1}\right)  {v_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_0}\right)  {v_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } y\right) -\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_3}\right)  {v_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_2}\right)  {v_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_1}\right)  {v_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_0}\right)  {v_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } x\right)}{J}
$$

$$ u_{10} = \frac{\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_3}\right)  {w_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_2}\right)  {w_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_1}\right)  {w_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_0}\right)  {w_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } y\right) -\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_3}\right)  {w_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_2}\right)  {w_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_1}\right)  {w_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_0}\right)  {w_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } x\right) }{J}
$$

$$
u_{01} = \frac{\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_3}\right)  {v_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_2}\right)  {v_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_1}\right)  {v_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_0}\right)  {v_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } x\right) -\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_3}\right)  {v_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_2}\right)  {v_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_1}\right)  {v_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_0}\right)  {v_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } y\right) }{J}
$$

$$
u_{11} = \frac{\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_3}\right)  {w_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_2}\right)  {w_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_1}\right)  {w_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \eta } {N_0}\right)  {w_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } x\right) -\left( \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_3}\right)  {w_3}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_2}\right)  {w_2}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_1}\right)  {w_1}+\left( \frac{d}{d \xi } {N_0}\right)  {w_0}\right)  \left( \frac{d}{d \xi } y\right) }{J}
$$

and

$$
J = \left( -\frac{\left( \eta +1\right) \, {x_3}}{4}+\frac{\left( \eta +1\right) \, {x_2}}{4}+\frac{\left( 1-\eta \right) \, {x_1}}{4}-\frac{\left( 1-\eta \right) \, {x_0}}{4}\right)  \left( \frac{\left( 1-\xi \right) \, {y_3}}{4}+\frac{\left( \xi +1\right) \, {y_2}}{4}-\frac{\left( \xi +1\right) \, {y_1}}{4}-\frac{\left( 1-\xi \right) \, {y_0}}{4}\right) -\left( \frac{\left( 1-\xi \right) \, {x_3}}{4}+\frac{\left( \xi +1\right) \, {x_2}}{4}-\frac{\left( \xi +1\right) \, {x_1}}{4}-\frac{\left( 1-\xi \right) \, {x_0}}{4}\right)  \left( -\frac{\left( \eta +1\right) \, {y_3}}{4}+\frac{\left( \eta +1\right) \, {y_2}}{4}+\frac{\left( 1-\eta \right) \, {y_1}}{4}-\frac{\left( 1-\eta \right) \, {y_0}}{4}\right)
$$

$$
N_0 = \frac{\left( 1-\eta \right) \, \left( 1-\xi \right) }{4}
$$

$$
N_1 = \frac{\left( 1-\eta \right) \, \left( \xi +1\right) }{4}
$$

$$
N_2 = \frac{\left( \eta +1\right) \, \left( \xi +1\right) }{4}
$$

$$
N_3 = \frac{\left( \eta +1\right) \, \left( 1-\xi \right) }{4}
$$

Comment: There's no one non-numerical strategy for all such $W$, but if you make the question about the $W$ you care about, we might know a non-numerical strategy that works for it.

Comment: I'll post $W$ shortly. In the interim I just found a site about [the derivative of an integral function](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2018/10/10/Autograd-and-the-derivative-of-an-integral-function/). Is this really a thing? This is the the most relevant resource that I can find on the subject.

Comment: Yes, [it's really a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: @J.G. The formula reduces to what I already have as my limits are constant. Here is the [expression](https://gist.github.com/sola-aina/2b01960b9e408f810dc471080e44e1c8) $W$. Its really big. I had to export it from maxima. You may have to save it as html in order to view it. I am not optimistic about an analytic integral.

Comment: You should give $W$ as MathJax in the question, not HTML in a comment. Maybe $W$ or your integral has a more concise definition as "the solution to this problem". I suspect we may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here.

Comment: @J.G. I've posted the equation for $W$ but not in the full expanded form, as it exceeded the char limit for posts.

Comment: Maybe ask a question about one term. A lot of them look similar enough to succumb to the same methods. Or maybe you need a question of the form, "I want to do this thing, which I tried this way, but that reduced to integrating something incredibly verbose" so we can say, "instead of what you tried that got that, do this".